# How to get out of a function in php

Tags: php

I have the following function:

```
function authenticate($req, $resp, $args) {
    $credentials = json_decode($req->getBody());

    $sql = "SELECT usr_password FROM ict_users WHERE usr_username='".$credentials->username."'";
    try {
        $db = DB_Connection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $password = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }

    if (password_verify($credentials->password, $password[0]->usr_password)) {
        echo 'Valid password !';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalide password !.';
    }
}
```

If I put `return;` after `$db = null;` will it stop executing my function? Or is there a better way to stop the function when an error is caught?

Comment: When an error is caught you have to exit at that point if you want to stop.

Comment: so what I must add to do that?

Comment: I want to stop the function of my request didn't find anything to be mor eprecise

Comment: Return works, I just didn't put it in the wright place

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)? It says: *"If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call"*. Pretty clear, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an `try {}catch(){}`  block, why not `throw new Exeption();` instead of `return null`. And `return null` is not done if you want "stop the function when an error is caught", you just returning `null` from the function.

Comment: try adding throw new Exeption('wrong credentials'); and it tells me that "Class 'Exeption' not found"

Comment: That's because Exception is misspelled.